# How to create a custom button cursor

Tags: html, css

I have this button:

```
<button/>
```

and when I place the cursor over it - the cursor turns into a hand pointer.

But instead of the hand pointer - I would like to display a custom icon.
Is this possible with the button element?

Comment: You can `cursor:url();` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor#url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`cursor:url()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

```css
button{
  cursor:url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1), pointer;
}
```

```html
<button>Spectric</button>
```